# Get azure storage table field type

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am retriving coudTable like this

```
$cloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name devAuctioneersCustomers –Context $ctx).CloudTable
```

and rows

```
$Rows = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

and I have all data, but how to get edm type of every field ?
I need this since I want to copy that table and there are not any tools in azure for this.

Comment: Do you want to copy data from a table to another table?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS yes, or to file and then from file to table but i am loosing edm type

Comment: For some reason I thought Microsoft Storage Explorer has this import/export feature where you can download a table in CSV format and then import the data in another table. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also you can take a look at Cerebrata Cerulean (https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean). It has a feature of copying data from one table to another. You can copy selected entities, entities matching a query or all entities from one table to another in same or different storage account. [Full Disclosure: I am behind this product].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply use `.GetType()` method on each column.

Here is the test at my side:

[image]

And if you want to copy table to another table, you can use `AzCopy version 7.3`. See the **Note** in this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#download-azcopy).